# Can I use a 30A+ PCB relay to drive an AC Motor instead of a DIN Rail Contactor?

Tags: pcb, motor, relay, motordriver, contactor

I have a project that involves a microcontroller switching on and off an AC motor (water pump) of no more than 1hp. I found these interesting [contactors](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005269770639.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.17.33763yEr3yEr7m&algo_pvid=341a860f-60c3-4acd-914c-523f58217c69&algo_exp_id=341a860f-60c3-4acd-914c-523f58217c69-8&pdp_npi=4%40dis%21SAR%2165.69%2132.85%21%21%2117.06%218.53%21%40211b612817071362255087597e23eb%2112000032428772306%21sea%21SA%212719572463%21AB&curPageLogUid=yoUaG7oTotzq&utparam-url=scene%3Asearch%7Cquery_from%3A) on aliexpress but I was wondering if I can replace them with a PCB relay with similar specs.

I found these relays from [CIT](https://www.citrelay.com/Catalog%20Pages/RelayCatalog/J115F1.pdf) and [American Zettler](https://www.azettler.com/pdfs/az2100.pdf) that have decent motor load ratings.

Comment: An inflated 25A 220V/230V AliExpress spec vs an actual branded datasheet that says it can actually do 2 hp motors at 250V... Where is the actual question?

Comment: Using PCB relays to drive simple AC motors is common practice, just check what current they are rated for. Obviously you shouldn't buy anything from Aliexpress unless you are looking to start a fire.

Comment: @jeroen3 The question is as in the title, whether it is possible to use PCB relays instead of contactors if their rating is high.

Comment: @lundin Thanks for the answer, I didn't know it was a common practice. I read in multiple sources that PCB relays are not reliable for driving motors and this was my concern

Comment: There are lots of bad relays out there for sure. Buy a well-known brand and it is fine. Although mind clearage/creepage, obviously. Leaving air gaps scored into the PCB between the contacts is one common way to avoid creepage problems.